# connect robomongo to mongoDB docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, robo3t

I'm running a `NodeJS` App with [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). Everything works fine and I can see all my data by connecting to Mongo inside container. But when I connect to [RoboMongo](https://robomongo.org/) I don't see any data.

How can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Can you please share some details or probably a screenshot of what you have tried so far?

Comment: hey Siddharth Ajmera i just  try to see my datas using robomongo but it doesnt show anything, mongoDB is running inside a docker container

Comment: Can you see your databases and collections listed in RoboMongo?

Comment: i just see my database name but collections are not shown :(

Comment: Double click on your collection. You'll get 3 folders in a hierarchy : Collections, Functions, Users.

Double Clicking on your collections will show you your collections in that database.

Comment: Yes sur but in my case collections(0) its empty

Comment: That's strange. Which version of RoboMongo and MongoDB are you using?

Comment: it works very fine when i'm using the local mongoDB but this problem is provided when mongoDB instance is running inside docker container

Comment: Maybe you should do a Robomongo SSH tunnel connection to MongoDB inside docker container.

Comment: André Bonna thanks for replying even if i dont have any idea about this : D i will look  how to do this

Comment: I am working on and answer. Hang on! =)

Comment: Can you make a simple SSH connection to Docker container?

Comment: i'm docker newbie cant do this inside docker container,thanks  André Bonna for ur help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do a Robomongo SSH tunnel connection to MongoDB inside docker container. First of all you should install a ssh server inside your docker container.

> https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/

---

After that you should configure your connection in Robomongo.
Inside "Connection Settings" there are configuration tabs of your Robomongo Connection.

Go to "SSH" Tab and configure your SSH connection to the docker container. After that go to "Connection" Tab and configure your connection to MongoDB as if it was in localhost scope.

Comment: Didn't work for me, so i found a workaround which is better aligned with the docker philosophy : made an ssh docker as described, then run it with a `-link _mymongodocker_` parameter (and a port mapping for 22 so i'm sure to find it easily). Then in robomongo instead of localhost i use mymongodocker (as it's linked, it's available from the ssh docker). 

Works like a charm even if --link is deprecated and should be replaced by a more modern approach, for the time beeing, i'm too lazy :)

Answer (score 24):

There is another way. You can

1. SSH with Robomongo into your actual virtual server that hosts your docker applications (SSH tab, check "Use SSH tunnel" and complete the other fields accordingly)
2. Now ssh into the same machine in your terminal.
3. `docker ps` should show you your MongoDB container.
4. `docker inspect <mongo container id>` will print out complete information about that container. Look for `IPAddress` in the end, that will give you the local IP of the container.
5. In the "Connection" tab in Robomongo use that container IP to connect.

**Another sidenote:** *Make sure that you don't expose your mongodb service ports in any way (neither Dockerfile nor docker-compose.yml), cause that will make your database openly accessible from everywhere. Assuming that you don't have set up a username / password for that service you will be scanned and hacked soon.*

Comment: That's the only valid answer for me as I'm on a cloud server and I surely won't expose my database port or alter any of my containers. Thank you!

Comment: i have used ecpose in my docker compose file. This only opens port inside the server. So you can you use expose but not ports. This will open it for everybody. Somebody disagree?

Comment: Finding the IP address of the MongoDB container was useful, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to enable forwarding the Mongo Container itself, here's how my docker-compose looks like.

```
mongo:
  image: mongo
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
```

Comment: for development purpose I am use this method

Comment: I have the same settings but it seems that my API uses a different DB (probably the one in the docker container). How do I actually connect there with a tool such as Robo3T or Robomongo?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing a different problem. I had installed MongoDB locally. So, when the MongoDB on docker was running, it was clashing with the one running on my host. I had installed it using `brew`.

So, I ran

`brew services stop mongodb-community`

and then I restarted Robo3t. I saw the databases created in the MongoDB running on the docker.

Voila!

Comment: dude that helped out!  thank you for this tidbit. Future folks reading: definitely check this out if you installed mongo with brew before trying to connect to mongo running in a container.

Comment: @finiteloop Glad to be of help :)

Comment: This should be the go-to solution in most cases. Thanks for this man

Comment: @SeanKonig Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

Please note that maybe you won't be able to use ssh because it was just a problem of incompatibility between mongo and robomongo.

'Robomongo v8.5 and lower doesn't support MongoDB 3'. It has nothing to do with docker.

Answer (score 0):

**First log in with ssh Login details**

1. ssh -i yourpemfile.pem username@ipaddress
   [image]
2. Check running container id for MongoDB

   docker ps -a
3. then check the mongo container id

docker inspect container_id

[image]

4. Then open robo3t

create new connection and add container id
use ssh login details to connect to mongodb

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -3):

In your docker-compose file, you can **expose a port** to the host.

For example, the following code will expose port 27017 inside the machine to the port 27018 in the host.

```
app:
  image: node
  volumes:
    - /app
  ports:
    - "27018:27017"
```

Then, if you have **docker-machine** installed and your machine is **default**, you can do in a terminal :

```
docker-machine ip default
```

It will give you the ip of your host, for example *192.168.2.3*. The address of your database (host) will be *192.168.2.3* and the port *27018*.

If your docker machine is not virtual and is your OS, the address of your database will be *localhost* and the port *27018*.

Comment: yes haverchuck this is what i did but it seems that for robomongo it needs some more configurations:)