# connect robomongo to mongo instance running inside docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker, robo3t

I'm connecting my Mongo database running inside a docker container with Robomongo, but I can only see the database name and collections(0) even if the database is full of data.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35720529/connect-robomongo-to-mongodb-docker-container